# Split column value to a new row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table like this:

| id | description | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Women clothing | T-shirt & Bottom & Top |
| 124 | sports items | badminton racket |
| 125 | gadgets | iphone & airpod & charging |

I want to split the column `items` value to a new row for each one item like this:

| id | description | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Women clothing | T-shirt |
| 123 | Women clothing | Bottom |
| 123 | Women clothing | Top |
| 124 | sports items | badminton racket |
| 125 | gadgets | iphone |
| 125 | gadgets | airpod |
| 125 | gadgets | charging |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create function check this screenshot. select your db and execute following: [image]

If you dont have string_split func. (below sqlserver2016) you can use this function , its working in our production enviroment for years :

```
USE xxx
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[StringSplit]
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), 
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), 
 cteTally(N) AS (
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

---

and query :

```
select * from 
(SELECT 123 id,      'T-shirt & Bottom & Top' T UNION ALL
 SELECT 124 ,     'badminton racket'UNION ALL
 SELECT 125 , 'iphone & airpod & charging' ) x
CROSS APPLY dbo.StringSplit(x.T, '&')
```

Comment: Sorry, can I know where should I create this function at ? I am new to this.

Comment: ok adding a screenshot for you

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: You should learn about the `VALUES` constructor, it's much shorter than all that `UNION ALL`

Comment: Thank you for the helping me on this. Appreciate it .

Answer (score 4):

```
WITH CTE(id ,description,items) AS
(
 SELECT 123, 'Women clothing' , 'T-shirt & Bottom & Top' UNION ALL
 SELECT 124 ,'sports items' ,'badminton racket'UNION ALL
 SELECT 125 ,'gadgets' ,'iphone & airpod & charging'
)
SELECT C.ID, C.DESCRIPTION, TRIM(S.VALUE)
FROM CTE AS C
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(C.items, '&') S;
```

Comment: Great Code @Sergey

Comment: @NAJAA BAZILAH don't forget to mark as answer.

Comment: My SQL Server does not have the STRING_SPLIT function.

Comment: What is the output for SELECT @@VERSION

Comment: @Sergey the  @@VERSION   it returns  version of your SQL Server . something like Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19043: )  
you can use as :  SELECT  @@VERSION

Comment: @Sergey The return output for the version is Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 3):

**you can use following SQL server code easily:**

```
select Tbl.RowID,
       Tbl.ColMain,
       [value] ExtractedValue from 
(
SELECT 123 as RowID,      'T-shirt & Bottom & Top' As ColMain UNION ALL
 SELECT 124 ,     'badminton racket' UNION ALL
 SELECT 125 , 'iphone & airpod & charging' 
 ) Tbl
CROSS APPLY String_Split(Tbl.ColMain, '&')
```

[image: Output]

Comment: @NAJAA BAZILAH  Enjoy my sister.